# Excel Data Validation with multiple criteria

Tags: excel

Can i do excel validation formulas with multiple conditions? I have one column where i want 1) unique values 2) All the values must either be 1-20 or 100000-399999 3) All have to be numbers

Comment: Try writing simple formulas on your sheet that will evaluate to true then combining them within `And` in your CF formula.

Comment: I do not the formula for the range 1-20 and 100000-399999

Comment: Check This: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php

Answer (score 0):

Select the column where you want the Data Validation, Choose Custom and use the following formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A1),COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1,OR(AND(A1>=1,A1<=20),AND(A1>=100000,A1<=399999)))
```

You can change A to the column you need.

- Isnumber() for numbers
- Countif() for unique value
- Or and And for the condition 1-20, 100000-399999